# Update One excel file based on a update in second file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have  :

- one sales data excel file (generated daily)
- another file called inventory data excel files 
  (updated when new stock comes in or new sales happen daily).

I want to automate the sales reflection on inventory.

Items sold on a particular day has to be deducted from the inventory sheet.

```
### Inventory Data ### Before Sale ####  
+---------+------+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+
| Item ID | 2415 | S  | M  | L  | XL | 2XL | 3XL |
+---------+------+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+
|    1001 |    9 |  4 |  2 |  3 |    |     |     |
|    1002 |   27 |  3 | 10 |  2 | 13 |     |     |
|    1003 |   17 | 10 |  6 |    |  1 |     |     |
|    1004 |   15 |  2 |  3 |  3 |  8 |     |     |
|    1005 |    8 |  6 |  1 |  1 |    |     |     |
|    1006 |   15 |  8 |  3 |  3 |  2 |     |     |
|    1007 |   20 | 15 |  4 |    |  2 |     |     |
|    1008 |   56 | 23 | 17 | 11 |  5 |     |     |
+---------+------+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+
```

---

```
### Sales Data ###        
+------+-----------------------------+--------------+------+----------+
| ID   |          Item Name          |      ID      | Size |  Buyer   |
+------+-----------------------------+--------------+------+----------+
| 1    |  Tee Russo Kisser(2014)-S   |         1002 | S    | beon1104 |
| 2    |  Tee ON THE PROWL(1042)-XL  |         1004 | XL   | jon4158  |
| 3    |  Tee TIGER GAZE(1049)-XL    |         1006 | XL   | jon4158  |
| 4    |  Tee DeadMan(2008)-XL       |         1007 | XL   | jon4158  |
+------+-----------------------------+--------------+------+----------+
```

---

```
### Inventory Data ### After Sale ####
+---------+------+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+
| Item ID | 2415 | S  | M  | L  | XL | 2XL | 3XL |
+---------+------+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+
|    1001 |    9 |  4 |  2 |  3 |    |     |     |
|    1002 |   27 |  2 | 10 |  2 | 13 |     |     |   <-- Sale 1
|    1003 |   17 | 10 |  6 |    |  1 |     |     |
|    1004 |   15 |  2 |  3 |  3 |  7 |     |     |   <-- Sale 2
|    1005 |    8 |  6 |  1 |  1 |    |     |     |
|    1006 |   15 |  8 |  3 |  3 |  1 |     |     |   <-- Sale 3
|    1007 |   20 | 15 |  4 |    |  1 |     |     |   <-- Sale 4
|    1008 |   56 | 23 | 17 | 11 |  5 |     |     |
+---------+------+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+
```

I have item ID consistent between two files. How can I automate this process?

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have added a relevant example.

Comment: @GC13 : Do you have any VBA knowledge? Is the sales file replaced every day or does its name change?

Comment: @R3uK I can learn VBA and sales file is new everyday.

Comment: See [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/828654-visual-basic-applications-open-copy-paste-close.html) for a base of VBA code. Then, you'll have to identify your daily file (or choose it manually) and paste the code at the end of a Table inside the Inventory with a test to avoid duplicate imports (I'd suggest another table with a list of imported file). Afterwards, you'll go through your "output" of inventory and remove corresponding quantity. Good luck for learning, but it's always more pleasant when it's done on a concrete project! ;)

Comment: @R3uK thank you. I will look at it.

Comment: @R3uK Is VBA the only option to solve this problem?

Comment: I think so, you won't avoid coding to tackle this, but if you want to go with another language you have an Excel interface with quite a lot of them now.

Comment: It seems that you have this information in an SQL database. Why use Excel? Creating a new query would be much better.

Comment: I have this information in Excel. I am trying to solve this using VLOOKUP and VBA Macro.

Comment: I have formatted the data as suggested by David in Comment#1 and added here for increasing the ease to understand the problem here.

Comment: Your: `### Inventory Data ### Before Sale ####  ` is inaccurate. It reveals the numbers of After Sales. Count them and you can see this is true. The numbers should be 9 28 17 16 8 16 21 56. Something tells me that you were not aware, but this is actually the inventory AFTER Sales ONLY.

Comment: @ejbytes, ### Inventory Data ### Before Sale #### is a representation of how the inventory can look like after the Inventory file is updated.
Once an item is sold, it should be reduced from the inventory worksheet.
Kindly ignore the column 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VLOOKUP, I was able to link two arrays in two different file having a common primary key and update it.

> =VLOOKUP(A2,'mySalesFile.xlsx'#$'sheet1 1'.$C$1:$D$7,2,0)

1. **A2** - is a row in inventory file worksheet (ITEM ID) which needs to be looked up.
2. **mySalesFile.xlsx** - Another file to look-up a value from.
3. **$C$1:$D$7** - Range array in which we want to look-up. (Target range from which we will look-up value A2.)
4. **2** - Return value from row 2 of range array.

Comment: The solution makes no sense for anything regarding the Question. You might as well just delete the question. There isn't anything useful for anyone, but yourself.